# How can I fill self intersected polygon drawed by PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, polygon

I drawed polygon by PIL ImageDraw.
Like This.

```
    points = [[100, 100],[150, 100],[150, 150],[130, 150],[130, 50],[140, 50],[140, 140],[145, 140],[145, 110],[100, 110],[100, 100]]
    with Image.new('RGBA', (200, 200), (0, 0, 0, 255)) as im:
        draw = ImageDraw.ImageDraw(im, 'RGBA')
        draw.polygon([tuple(point) for point in points], fill=(125, 125, 125, 255), outline=None)
        return im
```

And the result is,

[image]

The self intersected region is not filled by (125, 125, 125, 255). I think that PIL may use Even Odd fill rule. How can I fill self intersected region?? Or How can I use Nonzero winding fill rule?